# Combobox SelectedItemChanged event in a User Control

Tags: c#, combobox, event-handling

I have a user control consisting of a combobox and a label. In my application I need to enable or disable some other controls based on the selected value in that combobox. How do I access the SelectItemChanged event from the application?

Comment: Another more general question would be how do you access any event handler of a component inside a user control from the application?

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the event handler that will handle the event to your custom control. Something similar to the code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        YourUserControl userctr = new YourUserControl();

        //Sent the event handler linked to OnSelectedValueChanged
        userctrl.HandleSelectedValueEvent(new EventHandler(OnSelectedValueChanged));
    }

    private void OnSelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}

public partial class YourUserControl : UserControl
{
    public void HandleSelectedValueEvent(EventHandler handler)
    {
        this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += handler;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [SelectedValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged.aspx)

Comment: Either way...neither of those are available to set properties for in the application because the combobox is encapsulated in the user control...

Comment: Then youll need to tie another event or something back to the main application so you can update the other controls

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: See the following post at the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088023/forward-a-keypress-event/1090259#1090259 Think of the Form1 as your main application and Form2 as your user control.  Instead of OnKeyPress, use the SelectedValueChanged event i posted above